# NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject fails with an error when picking data from UserDefaults between Today widget and host app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass custom class between Today widget and host app. And I'm using NSKeyArchiver/NSKeyUnarchiver classes for that. My class conforms NSCoding protocol. Archiving with:

`widgetStorage = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.my")!
//value is [ListModel] 
let rawData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value)
widgetStorage.set(rawData, forKey: "myList")`

Unarchiving with:

`if let rawData = widgetStorage.data(forKey: "myList") {
 if let array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: rawData) as? [ListModel]`

That's perfectly works separately in widget and host app, but doesn't across. Today widget throws an error if data was archived in host app and vise versa.

An error report: 
'cannot decode object of class (ShoppingListToday.ListModel) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked'.

I can't get was is wrong, and what to do with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're facing is caused by swift using modulename.classname to reference a class. A fix for that is to tell the NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver to use a different class name for a type, I use the following extension for that:

```
extension NSCoding {
    func registerClassName() {
        let className = String(describing: type(of: self))
        NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName(className, for: type(of: self))
        NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(type(of: self), forClassName: className)
    }
}
```

You'll just need to call `registerClassName` before archiving or unarchiving the object

Here's the **static** version of the same:

```
extension NSCoding {    
    static func registerClassName() {
        let className = NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
        NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName(className, for: self)
        NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(self, forClassName: className)
    }
}
```

That way you can call it with YourClassName.registerClassName()

Comment: Thanks. Will try it and report back with results.

Comment: How can I call `registerClassName` when archiving if I didn't get any instances yet? Sorry, I'm pretty new in Swift

Comment: That's worked. Many thanks! But what a magic? Do you registered a type without module part in its name with this code, right? And is sufficient to call this method once at app launch? As it seemed to be true for me in tests.

Comment: This was the solution for me in regards to adding an Extension widget and passing data between the main view and the extension view.  I would have never figured that out!  Thanks!  (Note: I also had to register the class in my Extension just before retrieving the data)

Comment: Thanks! But how did you manage to discover the right reason? I've put 3 hours searching the problem before found your post.

Comment: Great solution! Don't forget to share this code for extending NSCoding both for the main app and for the extension/widget.